# Proof $L^{p}(X,\mu)$ is a linear space normed with respect to the norm

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

I am studying Lp-Spaces and Banach-Spaces
and the norm for $ p \in [1, \infty) $ is given by
$$||f||_{L_{p}}=\left ( \int _{X} ||f(x))||^{p} \right )^{1/p}$$
but i didn't find how to test it.
Do you know any book or pdf where I can find the demo? Thank you so much

Comment: Some search on MSE will give you several answers to your questions. Here is another [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2388647/121671)

Comment: @OliverDiaz I owe you!